# Where to place setContentView() in onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am a beginner in android and I want to know why is it that when I place my  **setContentView()** after defining the *TextView*, my **app crashes**, i.e

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS|Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES|
            Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     //After TextView 
}
```

But when I put my  **setContentView()** before defining the TextView then my app runs fine.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   //Before TextView
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS|Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES|
            Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
}
```

> Why it is that & and how adding  setContentView() before makes the
>   difference ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setContentView()` literally sets the views of your Activity. If you try to do something like `TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);`, then there is no view to find because you  haven't set your views yet, and thus your app crashes. This is why you should put `setContentView()` before you try to access your views.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any code you want before the `setContentView()` method as long as it doesn't refer to (parts of) the View, which isn't set yet.

Since your tv variable refers to the contents of the View, it can't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining setContentView() after you declared TextView you are doing wrong because the object Id that you are initializing in TextView is contained inside that layout is unknown in the class until the seConteView() executed.